# SVN Checkout libraries into subfolders

Tags: svn

I have an SVN repository with a few different projects.

- libs
- projecta
- projectb

Both projecta and projectb share the same libraries. I would like to be able to checkout the files, such that my folder structures appear

- projecta
- --- libs
- projectb
- --- libs

Is it possible to have projecta as an SVN project, with the libs folder checked out into a subfolder? I am assuming that I can make changes to libs, check it in, and then update all projects using libs? I'd really prefer to not have to make changes to libs outside of the project, then copy them across every time I want to integrate them (this is a PHP project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tortoise SVN Help has some options for [including a common sub-project](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html):

- externals
- nested working copy
- other options, which I consider less relevant to your question

I realize you may not be using Tortoise SVN, but a lot of the concepts still apply.

If you go the externals route, [you should consider using explicit revision numbers](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html):

> You should strongly consider using explicit revision numbers in all of your externals definitions, as described above. Doing so means that you get to decide when to pull down a different snapshot of external information, and exactly which snapshot to pull. Besides the common sense aspect of not being surprised by changes to third-party repositories that you might not have any control over, using explicit revision numbers also means that as you backdate your working copy to a previous revision, your externals definitions will also revert to the way they looked in that previous revision, which in turn means that the external working copies will be updated to match they way they looked back when your repository was at that previous revision. For software projects, this could be the difference between a successful and a failed build of an older snapshot of your complex code base.

Comment: It makes sense to mention this SVNBook chapter: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html

Comment: @bahrep - I had googled it but came up with the v1.0 link. It didn't seem to provide a lot of info, so I did not include it. Your link looks great though!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Externals was *exactly* what I needed, and I've incorporated into the projects. So far, it's working great and has already reduced the time it takes to achieve what I need to do. Kudos.